# Why is my Regex cutting off the last character of this mac address?

Tags: python, ios, regex, cisco

I am writing a Python script that connects to Cisco IOS devices and gathers specific information from specific commands.

I am trying to extra the MAC addresses that are listed in the "show log" command for unauthenticated devices. I have tried executing the command piping output to Regex directly within the IOS command line as I have seen multiple sources saying that it should work... yet I can't get that to work (not worried about that)

When I attempt to match the regex using Python, it is matching everything but cutting off the last character of the mac address.

Code:

```
macpattern = re.compile(r"([A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4})\w+")
for line in f:
        macTest = macpattern.findall(line)
        print(line)
```

An example MAC address is: "0024.c40c.4f45"

The output the Regex is giving is "0024.c40c.4f4", cutting off the last character. I do not understand why it is cutting it off. Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: Pattern "\w+" is being matched, which is outside your capture group. Remove "\w+" or change it to avoid matching alphanumeric characters. You can also change it to "\w?" to match 0+ times instead of 1+.

Comment: wooow that was it. I was just using the pattern that a regex builder gave :D
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
macpattern = re.compile(r"\b[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\b")
macResults = macpattern.findall(f.read())
print(macResults)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/l5rbJd/1).

The entire file is read into a string variable with `f.read()`, it is handier to use when you want to collect matches.

**EXPRESSION EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}         any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                           '0' to '9' (between 1 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}         any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                           '0' to '9' (between 1 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}         any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                           '0' to '9' (between 1 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```